# How to query a Postgress Table that is created by a kafka sink connector

Tags: postgresql, docker, psycopg2, pgadmin

i am using docker, postgres, pgadmin, kafka and ksql to analyze some data.

my docker-compose for postgres and pgadmin looks like this:

```
  postgres:
image: postgres
hostname: postgres
ports:
  - 5432:5432
environment:
  POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
  POSTGRES_DB: postgres
volumes:
  - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
restart: unless-stopped

pgadmin:
image: dpage/pgadmin4
depends_on:
  - postgres
ports:
  - 5555:80
environment:
  PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
  PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin
restart: unless-stopped
```

After starting up the docker, i am creating a source connector with a kafka topic from twitter -> Then i create a Stream which is listening to the source connector -> Afterwards i create a sink connector from the Kafka topic to Postgress.

When i log into the pgadmin page i can see, that the table with the name of the topic is created and values get inserted. In PGADMIN i'm able to query this table with: `"SELECT * FROM public."TWEETS_THIN""`

Now i'm trying to query this table via psycopg2. I'm creating the connection to the server via:

```
    import psycopg2

   try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgres' user='postgres' host='postgres' password='postgres'")
   except psycopg2.Error as e:
        print(e)

   try:
       cursor = conn.cursor()
       cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM public.TWEETS_THIN""")
       for item in cursor.fetchall():    
          print(item)
   except psycopg2.Error as e:
       print(e)
   cursor.close()
```

But i get the following error and don't know why:
current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

How can i query this table with psycopg2 ?

Comment: Something is happening _before_ you see that message that puts the connection into an invalid state.  This can be fixed by calling `conn.rollback()`, but really you should find the root cause and fix that.  Removing the try/excepts might help, because thn the program should crash immediately.

Comment: If you really really want to use UPPERCASE for your database objects, like a table name, you have to use double quotes " all the time. At least your Python code doesn't use double quotes around the table name.

Comment: @FrankHeikens thanks!! I just needed double quotes. 
Via cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM public."TWEETS_THIN" """) i'm able to get the data!